# AWS RDS: How to get hold of the Current Activity / Number of Connections?

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Using the AWS RDS console it is very easy to see the number of connections to an instance in the "Current Activity" column:
[image]

How do I get this information from the `aws` cli? As far as I can tell, [aws rds describe-db-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html) does not seem to have this particular piece of information.

NOTE: For my purposes, it would be enough to know if there are ***any*** connections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For metrics, you should be using the `aws cloudwatch` tool. To get the number of database connections currently, you could use something like this:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/RDS
--metric-name DatabaseConnections --start-time 2018-06-14T16:00:00Z
--end-time 2018-06-14T16:01:00Z --period 60 --statistics "Maximum"
--dimensions Name=DBInstanceIdentifier,Value=your-db-identifier
```

You'll need to combine it with code or a script to insert the correct `--start-time` and `--end-time` values.

Answer (score 0):

```
mon-get-stats --region "your-region" --metric-name="DatabaseConnections" --namespace="AWS/RDS" --dimensions="DBInstanceIdentifier=your-db-name" --statistics Maximum > your-db-name.txt

awk 'END{printf "%.0f",$3}' your-db-name.txt > your-db-name-final.txt

echo "$(cat your-db-name-final.txt)"
```

Above small script show your **RDS** Current Connections

Comment: The Cloudwatch CLI is no longer available: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/cli/CLIReference.html